# Heat map in Spotfire on geographic map?

Tags: spotfire

Is there any way to create a heatmap in Spotfire overlaid on a map? Such as,

[image: Heatmap example]

or, from Excel,

[image: Excel heat map]

I've seen the hexbin function, but the maps it produces are quite different.

Comment: I've accomplished similar results, but they were rectified. So the "heatmap" was bound by the lowest level of map dimension you have in your layers. For me it was zipcode, but if you has something more refined you could use this. It isn't as smooth as ArcGis and other applications--as in the edges are defined by your lowest visualization layer, but it's close.

Comment: How did you set it up? Is it a different visualization, or just a different way to display markers?

Comment: I'll post some stuff on Monday. I'm away from my office.  Sorry